# Javascript: check if for loop value in array

Tags: javascript

I have 30 users with id 1~30
And the  `memberInThisGroup` is an array `[2,24]`
And I want to check if the id is in the array(2,24)   then  give it the option with `selected`

```
string +="<option value=\""+data.userId+"\"  selected >"+data.userName+"</option>";
```

else , just a normal option

```
string +="<option value=\""+data.userId+"\">"+data.userName+"</option>";
```

Here is My code with error ,It seems like it just check one time,and the `selected` option is opposite
Please guide me how to write
thank you

```
function getCurrentusers(memberInThisGroup,groupId) {
    console.log(memberInThisGroup);  //2,24
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'currentusers',
        async : true,
        success : function(datas) {  
                //for loop every elements
                var string ="";
                for(var i in datas){
                    var data = datas[i];    
                    if(memberInThisGroup.indexOf(data.userId)){
                        console.log("We have member"+data.userId);
                        string +="<option value=\""+data.userId+"\"  selected >"+data.userName+"</option>"; 
                    }else{
                        console.log("We don't have member"+data.userId);
                        string +="<option value=\""+data.userId+"\">"+data.userName+"</option>";    
                    }
                }
                $("#e_"+groupId).append(string);    
                $('#e_'+groupId).multiSelect('refresh');            

        }
    });
}
```

`datas` ajax get is json like:

```
[{"userId":1,"userName":"Ken","password":"a12345","account":"ken@qq.com"},
{"userId":2,"userName":"wen","password":"qqqq","account":"wen@gmail.com"},
{"userId":3,"userName":"win","password":"1234","account":"win@gmail.com"},...]
```

Here is my console output:

```
We have member1
We don't have member2
We have member3
We have member4
We have member5
....
```

But what I expect is :

```
We have member2
We have member24
We don't have member1
We don't have member3
We don't have member4
We don't have member5
....
```

Comment: what is the error given?

Comment: Note that your code requires a shim for Array.prototype.indexOf to work in IE8 and below (or use this ES5 shim: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var string = "",
    memberInThisGroup = [2, 24], // just for test 
    data, selected;

for (var i = 0, len = datas.length; i < len; i++) {
    data     = datas[i];
    selected = (memberInThisGroup.indexOf(data.userId) >= 0) ? 'selected' : '';

    string += "<option value=\"" + data.userId + "\" " + selected + ">" + data.userName + "</option>"; 
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/xjeL5fp2/)

Comment: Thank youso much!! It works well.By the way,do you know where is the error in my logic??

Comment: 1. don't use `for..in` for `Arrays`. 2.  `indexOf` returns position or `-1` (if element does not exists in array) you need check result `>= 0` or `!== -1`,